# Get Data attribute using delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegation

This works great for me and I am able to `get data-club-id`:

```
<!-- this is an example -->
<a class="clubCode" href="" data-club-id= "1234">join with the code</a> 


$("a.clubCode").on("click",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
    var clubId = $(this).data('club-id');
alert(clubId)
});
```

but if I need to use delegation like here:

```
<a class="editReview" data-review-id="123" href="">Edit</a>

$(".eventFeedbackBottomContainer").on("click", "a.editReview", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var reviewId = $(this).data('review-id');
      alert(reviewId);        
});
```

`reviewId` returns `undefined`.

```
<div class="eventFeedbackBottomContainer">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#panel1" tabindex="1">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel2" tabindex="2">Hotels</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="rightFeedbackBottomContainer">
        <a href="/addReview/<?php echo escape($eventReview->getData()->race_id);?>/" id="" class="Smallbut">Add Review</a>
    </div>

    <div id="panel1" class="panel">
        <div class="feedbacksContainer">
            <div class="show-reviews"></div><!-- a.editReview is inside each review loaded from a javascript file in this div-->
        </div>                                
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="panel"/>
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see an `eventFeedbackBottomContainer` anywhere in your markup

Comment: sorry I thought was not the point of my question and I didn't post what I thought was irrelevant. I will add it now.

Comment: Strange. Any chance you can replicate the produced markup in a self-contained example, as it appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/xc3MC/

Comment: it also works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5J3aU/1/  Is 'editReview' inside 'eventFeedbackBottomContainer'?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 $(".eventFeedbackBottomContainer").on("click", "a.editReview", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var reviewId = $(this).attr('data-review-id');  //use  .attr() for accessing attibutes
    alert(reviewId);        
 });
```

**LIVE DEMO for pages prior to html 5:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/23XHj/7/

**LIVE DEMO in html 5 pages:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/23XHj/8/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: `.data` returns the HTML5 data-attribute value anyway, so the two in this case are probably equivalent.

Comment: @RGraham: oh since OP didnt mention anything as html5 or html4 page, i didnt notice that. well i have added a working fiddle with html5 styled code as well.

Comment: Using the `data-` implies HTML5, but even for a page marked with a <HTML4 doctype this will still not make a difference - if you replace `attr` with `data` in your Fiddle you'll notice they both work fine.

Comment: @RGraham: yep your right , i guess i just overlooked at the OP code. when you get so much involved in jquery, you often tend to forget the basics:P. anyway thanks for noticing that .

Answer (score 0):

[Check this article on event delegation.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

I only can think that your element of class 'editReview' wasnt a child of 'eventFeedbackBottomContainer'. Other than that seems to work as you wrote it.

[Link to Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5J3aU/2/)

```
<div class="eventFeedbackBottomContainer">
     ...
    <a class="editReview" data-review-id="123" href="">Edit</a>
    <a class="editReview" data-review-id="456" href="">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thought this myself at first, but OP says that `reviewId returns undefined` indicating that the alert did execute, but the `.data` didn't return

Comment: @RGraham: I couldnt replicate the 'undefined', either. Pure guess I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it. the problem was that

`<a class="editReview" data-review-id= "12345" href="">Edit</a>`

was inside `<div class="current-review"></div>`. Everything worked as soon as I moved it outside

here the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmauceri/5J3aU/4/)